Pumping lemma for o^i1^j | j>i ^ j >=0
I have this language $L =\{0^i1^j \;|\; i > j \land j \ge 0\}$.
When I apply the pumping lemma for regular languages taking $p=j$ and $s=0$, this language does not satisfy the lemma.
However, trying to do it with examples it seems the lemma is satisfied. I mean:
If I get the constant $p=2$ and the string $00$, by pumping any possible value of $y$, the pumped string has the format $00..00$ and it belongs to $L$. So it seems that the lemma is satisfied.
Can you tell me what my mistake is?

Instead of setting $p>0$, you should setting $p=0$ to decrease the length of the consequent string. When $p>0$, all consequent strings are in $L$. But when you consider the string $0^{n+1}1^n$ and $p=0$, it helps you to prove.
